# LOOKUPVALUE: Se proporcionó una tabla de varios valores donde se esperaba un sólo valor

Tags: powerbi

Al aplicar la fórmula de Power BI `LOOKUPVALUE` para obtener el valor de una tabla me salta el siguiente mensaje:

"Se proporcionó una tabla de varios valores donde se esperaba un solo valor"

El código de la fórmula es el siguiente:

```
Media PVP Familia = LOOKUPVALUE('Precios_medios'[Promedio de PVP];
'Precios_medios'[Ref. Familia];'Listado Inicial'[Ref. Familia])
```

La tabla de 'Precios_medios' es una tabla del tipo:

```
Ref. Familia     Promedio de PVP
3562             1.21
5968             2.35
...
```

y la tabla de 'Listado Inicial' es del tipo:

```
Producto      Ref. Familia
producto1     3562
producto2     3562
producto3     5968
....
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución aquí: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/LOOKUPVALUE-quot-A-table-of-multiple-values-was-supplied-where-a/m-p/331661#M148286

Gracias a todos